# Rendering a line followed by text

Tags: html, asp.net

Seems simple.

I need the look of :

__ My text Here.

Sort of an elongated bullet point followed by text if you will. 
The **_** is I assume, done with a `<HR/>` tag .
The `<HR/>` Tags works OK but the "my Text here" is rendered on the next line.
I have tried

```
<hr style='background-color:#000000;border-width:0;color:#000000;height:2px;line-height:0;text-align:left;width:5%;' /> <label>aaabb</label> <br/>
```

I have tried variations such as putting them in a table in the same row but I am unable to get the simple 'concatenated' look  I want.

Comment: Did you already try a table cell with a bottom border (and a 2nd cell for the text)? There dozens of ways to do this and it's really hard to tell what will look exactly like the way you want it.

Comment: Tried L.H. cell containing the hr tag and r.h. cell containing the text. What I am looking for is a line at mid character height followed by the text. Like an elongated Bullet Point followed by its text.Thx

Comment: Your text example is misleading since you are using underscore characters.

Comment: Sorry, I was torn between the solid underscore and the hypen which appears dashed. Opted for the underscore and explanation which obviously wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<hr style="width: 30px; float: left; margin-top:15px"><span style="white-space: nowrap;"> My text here.</span>
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9CvN6/

Comment: This does the trick. By altering the margin-top I can get the line mid char.

Answer (score 1):

or this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8RDL8/)

modified html:

```
<hr class="bullet"/><label>aaabb</label>
```

css:

```
hr.bullet {
    border:0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    color:#000000;
    height:2px;
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    margin-right:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are looking for `&mdash;`?

—My Text Here.

Comment: Just tried it it is only one char. Looking for unbroken line variable length. Thanks